# I need a jQuery.history workaround for refreshing

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using the jQuery.history plugin in my webpage and I am stuck with a little problem. I have the following layout for my webpage:

- www.myDomain.com
- www.myDomain.com/#home.php
- www.myDomain.com/#otherPage.php
- ... more of that

So when going to my website at `www.myDomain.com`, it actually loads `index.php`, which is quite logical. Inside `index.php`, I say: `include('home.php');`. So google can check the contents of my first page. `$.history` stores the `www.myDomain.com` link in its plugin. Which is still fine.

1. Now, I go through my menu and click on *Home*. Which will direct me to my homepage. But of course, I was already there. The problem is that the link of my *Home* button is `#home.php`, because I do an ajax request with `$.history`. So my webpage fades out and the same content is coming in.
2. When I am on *otherPage* and press `ctrl+R`, I first get my homepage and then the webpage is unloaded and *otherPage* comes in. Which is annoying, because I would like to get *otherPage* direct.

So my question is: How can I make sure, that the first page (so without a hash) is directly loaded when there is no hash? And how can I make sure that the homePage isn't loaded I am going to another hash?

It seems quite logical that it is going wrong, but I don't see the workaround, because PHP can't get the hash of the link. This is for the user agent only. And I was thinking about setting an extra variable or something when going to my page, but still, that would make the href's not the same anymore and `$.history` would not recognize the same links.

**UPDATE**

This demonstration actually shows what I am talking about:

http://balupton.com/sandbox/jquery-ajaxy/demo/

When you are on the page and scroll down to the TABS section. `Using jQuery Ajaxy` as header; It shows an empty section. And clicking the tabs will fill it of course. When refreshing the page, it will again start with the empty page and then fill it with the right content you wanted. My thing is: I don't want a blank starting page.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I created a workaround... finally.

In my main page, I do a standard `include()`. And do not set it to `display: none`. But I do so in a javascript later on with: `document.write('<style>#content{display:none;}</style>');`

So now, google will find the normal page. When someone loads the page. The first included page is just ignored. And because we init the `$.history object`, the page will do a `$('#content').show();` after the first ajax call.

PS. I would like to mention that I should have start off with the [jquery.address plugin](http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/), instead of this one. Maybe I'll refactor it someday.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest instead of #home.php, try to make it only #home, that way it will not load two pages one by one and will load only one page.

Ref: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jquery-history-web-2-0-hashchange-history-remote

Comment: No, now it won't either, because everything after # is not seen as loading. This is not what I am aiming for with this problem. The page is double loaded, because index.php has include(home.php) and after that, it says to $.history: let's load home.php. But I can't remove the include, because my page will be empty otherwise

Comment: I see a forward slash, not sure if it has to be added there. www.myDomain.com/#otherPage.php

Comment: You could also see it as: www.myDomain.com/index.php#otherPage.php. I just added the latter .php, because then I can send the complete hash to my ajaxReceiver.php?page=otherPage.php